# Java InputStream to Java8 Stream tokenizing

Tags: java-8, tokenize, java-io

Is there a way to get each word from a text file as a Java8 stream of Strings?

E.g. you have test.txt:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
```

You get the stream:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
Stream<String> s = br.lines();
```

And emit a stream of words (splitting at spaces), that you can `.forEach` print?

```
Lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet,
consectetur
adipiscing
elit,
sed
do
eiusmod
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your words are separated by  spaces:

```
    try (Stream<String> s = Files.lines(Paths.get("Your path"))
            .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s+")::splitAsStream)) {
        s.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```